# Sticky responsive top navigation bar with 3-line dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I have a simple sticky responsive top navigation bar with 3-line dropdown menu.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: inherit
        }

        .header {
            font-family: Consolas, Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000a98, #00B8FF);
            color: white;
            font-size: 15px;

        }

        .topnav {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000a98, #00B8FF);
        }


        .topnav a {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        .active {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000a98, #00B8FF);
            color: white;
        }

        .topnav .icon {
            display: none;
        }

        .dropdown {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;

        }

        .dropdown .dropbtn {
            font-size: 17px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            background-color: inherit;
            font-family: inherit;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            float: none;
            color: black;

            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .topnav a:hover,
        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #555;
            color: white;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .topnav a:not(:first-child),
            .dropdown .dropbtn {
                display: none;
            }

            .topnav a.icon {
                float: right;
                display: block;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav.responsive {
                position: relative;
            }

            .topnav.responsive .icon {
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
            }

            .topnav.responsive a {
                float: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
            }

            .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
                float: none;
            }

            .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
                position: relative;
            }

            .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: left;
            }

        }

        .content {
            padding: 16px;
        }

        .sticky {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .sticky+.content {
            padding-top: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">hhvvvvvvvvv
    </div>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <div class="dropdown">

            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>

    </div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");

            if (x.className === "topnav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }
        window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

        var navbar = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

        function myFunction() {
            if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
                navbar.classList.add("sticky")
            } else {
                navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', stickyNavigation);

    </script>
    <div style="padding-left:16px">
        <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>

        <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
        <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
        <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
        <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
        <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
        <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
        <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
        <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
        <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
        <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
        <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

To see the live demo of above code click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GKOP6M1JG0AZ)
Everything is fine but dropdown is not working. Before I tried to make navbar sticky, dropdown is working perfect but I am facing this problem after making navbar sticky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off the previous version of the answer, I found the reason why clicking on the 3 line menu dropdown (called a hamburger actually!) was not displaying when we were not at the top of the page.

This was because in your media query, you were setting the `.topnav.responsive` class to be `position: relative`, which opened up your menu at the top of the page, rather than where we were expecting to.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {
        position: relative; <--- This was causing the issue
}
```

To fix this, all you need to do is comment out the `.topnav.responsive` class here.

In addition, in the script provided, it does not account for the added `sticky` CSS class we have added. The example you were building off of was only using the `responsive` class dynamically and wasn't checking for the dynamic `sticky` class responsible for keeping the nav bar in the display of the user. To fix that, we will need to edit the logic of the script.

```
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");

            if (x.className === "topnav") { // this is only checking for responsiveness and not checking when the topnav has the `sticky` class
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }
```

To fix this, I updated the logic to only check for if the topnav has the `responsive` class attached to it.

```
function reactiveTopNav() {
    const topNav = document.getElementById('myTopnav');
    
    // checks if the topnav already has the class 'responsive'
    // if it does, remove it, else, add it in
    // this only checks for `responsive` and not any other class
    topNav.classList.contains('responsive')
        ? topNav.classList.remove('responsive')
        : topNav.classList.add('responsive');
}
```

Putting it together, this is what I had

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <style>
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000a98, #00b8ff);
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .active {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000a98, #00b8ff);
      color: white;
    }
    
    .topnav .icon {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      font-size: 17px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      float: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .topnav a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav a:not(:first-child),
      .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
      }
      .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      /* .topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
    } */
      .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }
      .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
        float: none;
      }
      .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
        position: relative;
      }
      .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
    
    body {
      padding-top: 16px;
    }
    
    .sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .sticky+body {
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">
                    Dropdown
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size: 15px" class="icon" onclick="reactiveTopNav()">&#9776;</a
            >
        </div>
        <script>
            function reactiveTopNav() {
                const topNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");

                topNav.classList.contains("responsive")
                    ? topNav.classList.remove("responsive")
                    : topNav.classList.add("responsive");
            }
            window.onscroll = function () {
                stickyTopNav();
            };

            var navbar = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

            function stickyTopNav() {
                if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
                    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
                } else {
                    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
                }
            }
        </script>
        <div style="padding-left: 16px">
            <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>

            <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
            <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
            <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
            <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
            <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
            <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
            <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
            <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
            <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
            <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
            <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `position: absolute;` with `position: fixed;`

```css
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed; /* <------------- */
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Example:**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: inherit
        }

        .header {
            font-family: Consolas, Helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000a98, #00B8FF);
            color: white;
            font-size: 15px;

        }

        .topnav {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000a98, #00B8FF);
        }


        .topnav a {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        .active {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000a98, #00B8FF);
            color: white;
        }

        .topnav .icon {
            display: none;
        }

        .dropdown {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;

        }

        .dropdown .dropbtn {
            font-size: 17px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            background-color: inherit;
            font-family: inherit;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            float: none;
            color: black;

            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .topnav a:hover,
        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #555;
            color: white;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .topnav a:not(:first-child),
            .dropdown .dropbtn {
                display: none;
            }

            .topnav a.icon {
                float: right;
                display: block;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav.responsive {
                position: relative;
            }

            .topnav.responsive .icon {
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
            }

            .topnav.responsive a {
                float: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
            }

            .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
                float: none;
            }

            .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
                position: relative;
            }

            .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: left;
            }

        }

        .content {
            padding: 16px;
        }

        .sticky {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .sticky+.content {
            padding-top: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">hhvvvvvvvvv
    </div>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <div class="dropdown">

            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>

    </div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");

            if (x.className === "topnav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }
        window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

        var navbar = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

        function myFunction() {
            if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
                navbar.classList.add("sticky")
            } else {
                navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        }

        //window.addEventListener('scroll', stickyNavigation);

    </script>
    <div style="padding-left:16px">
        <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>

        <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
        <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
        <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
        <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
        <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
        <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
        <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
        <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
        <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
        <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
        <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
        
   </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try by replacing the code you provided.

Comment: I uploaded an example where you can see that it works

Comment: Oops everything is fine but, by clicking on 3 line meny dropdown is not displaying!

Comment: Please help me! phttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/66546478/how-to-use-link-rel-license-tag-in-head-tag